# cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a slight problem converting a cURL to PHP cURL.

The cURL is:

```
curl -X POST https://api.curated.co/PUBLICATION_KEY/api/v1/email_subscribers -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Token token="API_KEY"' -d '{ "email" : "new_subscriber@example.com" }'
```

I'm converting it to:

```
<?php 
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Token token="API_KEY"'
);
$data = array("email" => "new_subscriber@example.com");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.curated.co/PUBLICATION_KEY/api/v1/email_subscribers');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);       
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

But I don't get any response.
**Note:** I'm changing my `API_KEY` and `PUBLICATION_KEY` with the proper ones.

I am following this guide: http://support.curated.co/hc/en-us/articles/201753981-Adding-Subscribers-with-the-API

Can you let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Is your request timing out or is there a response and you are just not looking at the response headers and such to see if they can help inform you of the problem? What does `var_dump(curl_getinfo())` show?

Comment: Is that your complete code? You need to do something with the `$result` variable?

Comment: There are no response headers ('Failed to load response data'). When I var_dump `$result` I just get `bool(false)`.

Comment: remove header `Accept` for now then, just to see response... or put just `Accept:` with no value there

Comment: Why are you using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"` instead of `CURLOPT_POST, true`?

Comment: Is it a fast fail or is the response timing out?

Comment: When I `curl_getinfo()` i get this: http://en.textsave.org/huyb I removed the Accept and changed the `POST` to true. The same result.

Comment: same result you mean `'Failed to load response data'` ?you can try to remove `Content-type` but it weird. so you are sure that curl command executes successfully on the same machine in shell?

Comment: `Failed to load response data` yep. If i remove `Content-type` no effect again. I didn't test it under shell, I will try now. It's my first time using cURL so I'm probably the main issue.

Comment: Have you tried using an invalid ApiKey? Do you get an error response? Or no response at all?

Comment: So if you never get it working in the shell, there could be huge amount of reasons :-) Do you have a link to documentation for this api? it is not about `converting` anymore :-)

Comment: Check for errors using `if(($result = curl_exec($ch)) === false) { echo 'error: ' . curl_error($ch); } else { // Success [your code here]}`

Comment: You have to make it work in shell first :-)

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. It's outside my area of expertise so I will leave it for someone who have more experience than me.

Comment: if you have possibility to regenerate api keys and token - you can give us the real key for tests, and reset them later once it's done

Comment: If they were mine I wouldn't care, but they are for a client. And in order to change them I have to call the support center. I will consult with someone of our developers when I get back to work tomorrow, they might have a better understanding of the task than me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely replace `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` If that doesn't change anything, you also might want to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` just in case Curated have a redirect involved (perhaps they have a separate auth layer, which then forwards you to the desired endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (:

To convert Curl command to PHP
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.curated.co/PUBLICATION_KEY/api/v1/email_subscribers");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"email\" : \"new_subscriber@example.com\" }");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Token token=\"API_KEY\"";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
```